# undefined method build_list (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

`user.build_book` does not seem to work. I get an `undefined method build_book` error. However,

```
a= user.book.build
a.save
```

does work. Why would that be?

`rails g migration add_user_reference_to_book user:references`

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :books
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to try explain your question,

parent.build_child(attributes) this for `has_one` relationship (parent has_one child)

if you using `has_many` then you should use parent.children.build(attributes)

if user has_one book then **@user.build_book** will work

if user has_many books then user **@user.books.build**